# Casting operator always ambiguous

Tags: c++, casting

Consider the following example:

```
struct m
{
    m(int ) { }
};

class q
{
public:

    int i;

    q(int i)
    {
        this->i = i;
    }

    operator double()
    {
        return (double) i;
    }

    operator m()
    {
        return (m)i;
    }
};

int main()
{
    q x(1);
    (m)x; // error: ambiguous
}
```

It fails when I call the casting: ambiguous conversion from `q` to `m`. Why so? I really don't get it. I explicitly added a casting operator for `m`! Why should that be ambiguous? If I remove the cast to `double`, however, this works. Why does that matter? How can I do what I want to do?

Comment: It also works if I remove the cast to double, but that in turn would mean losing performance when I just want to cast to a double.

Comment: How if the `mpf_class` defined? What is it?

Comment: mpf_class is one of the main classes in the GMP (Gnu Multiple Precision) library.

Comment: Have you tried using `explicit` before the `operator`?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the possible paths that the compiler can take when you do:

```
m temp__(x);
```

There are three relevant constructors:

```
m(int );      // (A)
m(const m& ); // (B)
m(m&& );      // (C)
```

We could call `(A)` via `x --> double --> int`, that is a user-defined conversion sequence.

We could call `(B)` or `(C)` via `x --> m`, that is also a user-defined conversion sequence.

A user-defined conversion sequence can only be preferences to another if they end up calling the same constructor. But in this case, they don't - so there's no way for the compiler to prefer one to the other. Hence, ambiguous.

Your alternatives would be to

- call your operator directly  (or make it a function with some name); or
- make `q` inherit from `m` - the derived-to-base conversion would be preferred to the user-defined conversion sequence; or
- make both conversion operators `explicit` - in which case there would only be one viable candidate to begin with, so there would be no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

When I compile your program with g++ 5.1, I get:

```
/home/imk/develop/so/mpf_cast/main.cpp:35:25: error: call of overloaded ‘__gmp_expr(q&)’ is ambiguous
     cout << (mpf_class) x << endl;
                         ^
/home/imk/develop/so/mpf_cast/main.cpp:35:25: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/imk/develop/so/mpf_cast/main.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1883:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(double)
   __gmp_expr(double d) { mpf_init_set_d(mp, d); }
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1880:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(float)
   __gmp_expr(float f) { mpf_init_set_d(mp, f); }
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1876:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(long unsigned int)
   __gmp_expr(unsigned long int l) { mpf_init_set_ui(mp, l); }
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1873:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(long int)
   __gmp_expr(signed long int l) { mpf_init_set_si(mp, l); }
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1869:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(short unsigned int)
   __gmp_expr(unsigned short int s) { mpf_init_set_ui(mp, s); }
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1866:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(short int)
   __gmp_expr(signed short int s) { mpf_init_set_si(mp, s); }
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1862:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(unsigned int)
   __gmp_expr(unsigned int i) { mpf_init_set_ui(mp, i); }
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1859:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(int)
   __gmp_expr(signed int i) { mpf_init_set_si(mp, i); }
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1855:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(unsigned char)
   __gmp_expr(unsigned char c) { mpf_init_set_ui(mp, c); }
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1852:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(signed char)
   __gmp_expr(signed char c) { mpf_init_set_si(mp, c); }
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1837:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(const __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>&)
   __gmp_expr(const __gmp_expr &f)
   ^
```

The problem cast expression `(mpf_class) x` requires an `mpf_class` (`typedef __gmp_expr<mpf_t, mpf_t> mpf_class`)
to be constructed from a `q`. So you might just as well consider

```
q x(1);
mpf_class m(x);
```

which provokes the same diagnosis.

Why is the construction ambiguous? Because:-

- There is, of course, no such constructor as `mpf_class(q const &)`
- Therefore, a conversion is required, if it exists, from `q` to one of the 11 other types,
  enumerated in the diagnosis, from which an `mpf_class` *can* be constructed.
- But there are *two* such conversions, each as good as the other, thanks to
  the two cast operators with which you have furnished `q`.

The conversion `operator double()` can satisfy the first of the 11 constructors
and `operator mpf_class()` can satisfy the last. The compiler has no basis
for preferring either of these constructors.

The problem will go away if you sacrifice one or other of your cast operators.
If you must have them both, then you can also solve it by making both of them
`explicit`, so that the compiler will not consider invoking the conversion unless it is explicity invoked:

```
explicit operator double()
{
    return (double)i;
}
explicit operator mpf_class()
{
    return (mpf_class)i;
}
```

Then you will find, e.g:

```
int main()
{
    q x(1);
    mpf_class mpf(x); // via `explicit operator mpf_class()`
    double d(x); // via `explicit operator double()`
    // d = q(2); <- does not compile
    d = static_cast<double>(q(2));
    // mpf = q(2); <- does not compile
    mpf = static_cast<mpf_class>(q(2));
    return 0;
}
```

Incidentally:

- The cast operators should be `const`
- Within a function it is superflous to cast the return value to
  the return type when an implicit conversion exists.

Hence:

```
explicit operator double() const
{
    return i;
}
explicit operator mpf_class() const
{
    return i;
}
```